# Как делать дочерние классы в pydantic?

Tags: python, pydantic

Я так понимаю, подобный способ в pydatic не работает. Как делать правильно?

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel


class _MainApp(BaseModel):
  port: int
  user_fs_path: str

  jwt_secret: str
  password_hash_secret: str

class _DataBase(BaseModel):
  port: int
  password: str

class _NewUser(BaseModel):
  default_space_available: int


# main
class CfgModel(BaseModel):
  main_app: _MainApp
  data_base: _DataBase
  new_user: _NewUser
```

```py
cfg: CfgModel = CfgModel( **getCfgFromToml() )
```

Comment: а не в pydantic он у вас работает что ли? как вы вообще делаете дочерние классы в ООП в python? у вас, кстати, весь код - это дочерние классы.

Comment: @strawdog я делал наподобие поджиков в джаве, мне надо такую структуру расписать `cfg.main_app.port`

Comment: py3.12 pydantic 2.53. не томл, а жсон (а какая разница если на выходе dict) - ваш код работает